# For each link where href equals myValue

Tags: jquery, html

Why is the following not changing the text to it worked?

```
//JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

$('a').each(function(i) {
    if($(i).attr("href") == "mywebsite.co.uk")
    {
        $(i).innerHTML = "It Worked!";
    }
});


//HTML:

<a href="mywebsite.co.uk"></a>
```

Debugging it doesn't seem to pick up the href value.attr but I may be getting it all wrong can someone please make sure I have the above correctly done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`i` is the index of the element, you want the element and should use should use something like:

```
// The first argument is the index, the second is the element
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).attr("href") == "mywebsite.co.uk")
    {
        $(element).html("It Worked!"); // Change this to .html()
    }
    console.log('Index is:'+index+', Element is'+element);
});​

<a href="mywebsite.co.uk"></a>
```

Also, I changed the `.innerHtml()` to `.html("content in here")`. To update the HTML inside the returned `<a></a>` tag `(element)`.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2scug/1/). http://jsfiddle.net/2scug/1/

Comment: Accepting your as you explained the element and index parameters to me.

Answer (score 9):

It may be shorter to write it as:

```
$('a[href="mywebsite.co.uk"]').each(function() {
    $(this).html("It Worked!");
});
```

There also is a reason why jQuery has html() function. It cleans up all possible memory leaks and then uses innerHTML internally to set the value you need ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Corrected:

```
//JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

$('a').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "mywebsite.co.uk")
    {
        $(this).html("It Worked!");
    }
});
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kAWdy/

**Edit 2019-12-06**
I was in a hurry to try to gain points when I wrote the initial answer and didn't take the time to create the concisest version. There is no need for `.each(...)`, JQuery selectors are used to get a set of elements and operations can be applied to the set. Like so:

```js
$("a[href='mywebsite.co.uk'").html("It Worked!");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="othersite1.co.uk">Foo</a> <br />
<a href="mywebsite.co.uk">Foo</a> <br />
<a href="othersite1.co.uk">Foo</a> <br />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try it:

```
$('a').each(function(i,v) {
    console.log();
    if($(v).attr("href") == "mywebsite.co.uk")
    {
        $(v).html('It worked!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the element parameter, but @JustAnil 's answer explained what "v" is so accepting his/hers as the answer that resolved my problem.

Comment: @Anicho ok, happy to be usefull in some way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. you can check demo link here

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp75/1/For%20each%20link%20where%20href%20equal

```
<a href="mywebsite.com">
</a>
<a href="mywebsite.co.uk">
</a>
<a href="mywebsite.us">
</a>
<a href="mywebsite.in">
</a>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Get Text"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("a").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('href').trim() == "mywebsite.co.uk") {
                $(this).html("UK Website Link");
            } else {
                $(this).html("Website Link");
            }

        });
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
a{
  display:block;
}
input[type=button]{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp75/1/For%20each%20link%20where%20href%20equal

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of [the array functions available to you in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp).

Here is [the most minimal solution I could come up with](https://codepen.io/JackalopeZero/pen/OJPyJEo):

```
$('a')
.filter('a[href*="mywebsite.co.uk"]')
.text('It worked!');
```